# Mysql slave last error and sql thread

Tags: mysql, monitor

I use the `show slave status\G` and the result is as follows:

```
         Slave_IO_Running: Yes
        Slave_SQL_Running: No
          Replicate_Do_DB: 
      Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
       Replicate_Do_Table: 
   Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
   Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
               Last_Errno: 1008
               Last_Error: Error 'Can't drop database 'hehe'; database doesn't exist' on        query. Default database: 'hehe'. Query: 'drop database hehe'
```

And I guess the reason `Slave_SQL_Running` being `NO` is that the `Last_Error`, because I handly create a table on the master db before I build the master-slave cluster, and then I drop the table on the master.

Is there a way to alert people when this situation is occured? Like sending mail or sms?

Answer (score 1):

Best way is

> Manually: Execute SHOW GLOBAL STATUS like 'slave_running' and SHOW
>   SLAVE STATUS periodically and store it in a file. Check the contents
>   of the file periodically to see if any of your replicas have stopped
>   replicating. On Linux, you can have a cron job setup which executes
>   these queries periodically and even configure to send email alert if
>   slave_running value is ‘NO’.

For [more](http://blog.webyog.com/2012/11/20/how-to-monitor-mysql-replication/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I realized that some bash codes could do this just now.